# ConfirmationDialog cancel bug in swiftui

Tags: swift, swiftui

When I jump to the settings page and click Cancel in the pop-up dialog box, it will automatically return to the home page. How can I avoid this problem?

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var settingActive: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            TabView {
                VStack {
                    
                    NavigationLink(destination: SettingView(), isActive: $settingActive) {
                        EmptyView()
                    }

                    Button {
                        settingActive.toggle()
                    } label: {
                        Text("Setting")
                    }
                }
                .padding()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SettingView: View {
    
    @State private var logoutActive: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button {
                logoutActive.toggle()
            } label: {
                Text("Logout")
            }
            .confirmationDialog("Logout", isPresented: $logoutActive) {
                Button("Logout", role: .destructive) {
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with using `TabView` inside `NavigationView`.

You can solve this by moving `TabView` to be your top level object (where it really should be), or replacing `NavigationView` with  the new `NavigationStack`.

Here's an implementation that also removes the deprecated `NavigationLink` method:

```
enum Router {
    case settings
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var path = NavigationPath()
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            NavigationStack(path: $path) {
                VStack {
                                        
                    Button {
                        path.append(Router.settings)
                    } label: {
                        Text("Setting")
                    }
                }
                .navigationDestination(for: Router.self) { router in
                    switch router {
                    case .settings:
                        SettingView(path: $path)
                    }
                }
                .padding()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SettingView: View {
    
    @Binding var path: NavigationPath
    @State private var logoutActive: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button {
                logoutActive = true
            } label: {
                Text("Logout")
            }
            .confirmationDialog("Logout", isPresented: $logoutActive) {
                Button("Logout", role: .destructive) {
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `NavigationStack` supports iOS16 and above, I need to support iOS15, is there a better way?

Comment: As I mentioned in the answer… _"You can solve this by moving TabView to be your top level object (where it really should be)"_. This seems to resolve it in my testing

Comment: Sorry I overlooked the tip, it works, thanks a lot

Comment: After `TabView ` moves to the top layer, it will face the problem that `TabView ` cannot be hidden when pushed to the next page. Hiding `TabView ` is another problem. There are many discussions here, but there is no simple and effective solution.

Comment: Yes - it's easy to achieve on iOS 16+, but not iOS 15.